# Automatic MOLAP Error Notification

Tags: ssas, olap

We are just setting up a number of SSAS Cubes using pro-active caching and one thing that concerns me is how we will know if cube processing fails.

Is there a way to get SQL Server to notify via email if something has fallen over?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to process your cube from a SQL Agent job, there you can set up a notification so that if the job fails someone gets notified.

I have jobs that process cubes every hour and I use the method above